# Installing WinDBG

Tags: debugging, windbg

What is the best way to install WinDBG now?

It use to be very simple to download i.e. there was a small executeable.  I have tried some of the links on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx, some of them being very large.  I thought the "standalone" version would do the trick.  Still there is no entry in All Programs for Windows Debugging Tools (x86 or x64).

Comment: Also, once installed you can simply xcopy the entire install directory to a new machine.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen, thanks.  +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to run the "standalone" executable twice.  Dot Net version 4 is installed on the first run.

Answer (score 2):

The setup mentioned in your link is a "Download and Installable setup".

Navigate to this option

> Install Debugging Tools for Windows as Part of the Windows SDK

Start the setup. It asks for **local download** or **direct install** option. Click local download option.

The setup will get downloaded to your local machine